# List species names in local MySQL EnsEMBL database via PyCogent?

Tags: python, mysql, database, bioinformatics, biopython

We have a local EnsEMBL MySQL database containing annotated mosquito genomes.

The PyCogent cookbook states [**Here**](http://pycogent.org/examples/query_ensembl.html#query-ensembl) that you can access/query data from a local MySQL EnsEMBL database via the `cogent.db.ensembl.HostAccount` module. [**Here**](https://github.com/pycogent/pycogent/tree/master/cogent/db/ensembl) is the source code for PyCogent's ensembl-api.

But I cannot access the data as the functions assume *a priori* that I know the exact names of species (string) whose genomes I am trying to query... After hours of searching online, I would greatly appreciate if somebody could tell me how I can list the names of species (that PyCogent would understand) so that I can finally query the local database for the genome data.

This code shows my problem, note the commenting:

```
Release = 73

from cogent.db.ensembl import HostAccount, Genome

acc = HostAccount('localhost', 'username1', 'password1')  # login details to MySQL server

genome = Genome(Species='?????',Release=73,account=acc)   # Where can I find the available Species list so I can replace the '?????'
```

Comment: cross posted on biostars: http://www.biostars.org/p/91192/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a useful tip from @dpryan79 (from Biostars) I looked at PyCogent's source code and it turns out the only way I could view species names available was by actually logging into the MySQL server and listing the databases, the database names themselves require a naming convention whereby the first two strings delimited by underscores (_) are the genus and species names respectively.

So by logging into the mysql server via terminal:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser1 -ppass1
```

Then typing:

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

I can see the species available by looking at the names of each database, specifically the first two strings delimited by underscores, e.g. the following databases listed:

```
anopheles_gambiae_core_1312_73_1
anopheles_arabeinsis_core_1312_73_1
anopheles_funestus_core_1312_73_1
anopheles_gambiaeM_core_1312_73_1
```

Suggest I have the following species available: `anopheles gambiae, anopheles arabeinsis, anopheles funestus` and `anopheles gambiae type M`